# SiwftUI Preview not working for MacOS build whereas it works fine for iOS builds

Tags: ios, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I am new to SwiftUI, building a multi-platform app in SwiftUI when building the app for iOS the preview works fine but when I change the target to macOS and select MyMac the preview stops working and says "Select a scheme that builds a target which contains the current file or this file to a target that is built by the current scheme ". Additionally, it even complains that it cannot find my views in scope.

[image: Scope Error Screenshot]

[image: Preview Error Screenshot]

[image: Preview when building for iOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your second screenshot: Look at the current file’s Target Membership in the sidebar, which shows the macOS target is NOT checked. You need to check that box for all files required by the Mac app.